# how to exclude nested node_module folders from a loader in webpack

Tags: filepath, webpack

Will the following `exclude: '/node_modules/'` only exclude the node_modules folder in the same directory, or will it also exclude the nested node_module folders? If not: how can I adjust it to exclude all the node_module folders?

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader',exclude: '/node_modules/' } 
    ]
},
```

Filestructure:

```
/general
/node_modules
/mod1
     /src
     /node_modules
/mod2
     /src
     /node_modules
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders) says that

> A condition may be a RegExp, a string containing the absolute path, a function(absPath): bool, or an array of one of these combined with “and”.

So based on that you could try to build a RegExp to fit your case.

Personally I prefer to use `include` over `exclude` as a whitelist is easier to maintain than a blacklist. At least you have stronger control this way.

Following this line of thought you could skip `exclude` problem altogether and build a rule like this:

```
include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'general'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'mod1/src'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'mod2/src')
]
```

Of course if you have more complicated structure maybe you'll end up doing a combination of both. One rule to `exclude` *node_modules* and one rule to `include` the directories you want to look into.

Comment: This is the example the documentation was missing. Awkwardly, neither DevDocs nor the official documentation made it straightforward to search for `include` usage. Thanks for this example using an Array.

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is only with TypeScript files, you can take advantage of the fact that `'ts-loader'` will use your `tsconfig.json` file upon compiling. You can define paths you want to exclude right there instead.